# Hi, I'm working angular 3n 2 rc5, and I would like that to ejecutrar function (change) perform two functions

Tags: angular

I have this code, and I need to give value to the variable and simultaneously execute a function, as I can solve thanks.  I've done as follows, but not if it is correct, some help.

view.html

```
<input #five_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="estrellas[5] = five_starscb.checked (change)= "filterHotels()" >
<input #four_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="estrellas[4] = four_starscb.checked" (change)="filterHotels()">
 <input #three_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="estrellas[3] = three_starscb.checked" (change)="filterHotels()">
<input #two_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="estrellas[2] = two_starscb.checked" (change)="filterHotels()">
<input #one_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="estrellas[1] = one_starscb.checked" (change)="filterHotels()">
```

component.ts

```
export class HotelComponent { 
public estrellas: any[] = [0,false,false,false,false,false];

filterHotels(){
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(this.estrellas);
   this._hotelService.filter(myJsonString).subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.status = response.status;
},
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.errorMessage = <any>error;

                    if (this.errorMessage != null) {
                        console.log(this.errorMessage);
                        alert("Error en la petición");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
}
}
```

Comment: cant you pass the value into function, and set the value in the function?

Comment: The function is responsible for database search according to the array of estrellas[] because i have 5 inputs with differents stars.

Comment: Can u add more code showing how you are using esrellas?

Comment: worth that I have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try below,

```
// create a new method 
setandfilterHotel(id,val){
   this.estrellas[id] = val;
   this.filterHotels();
}
// and use like below
<input #five_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="setandfilterHotel(5,five_starscb.checked)">
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try making one function out of it and doing something like this:

```
<input #two_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="filterHotels(2, two_starscb.checked)">
<input #one_starscb type="checkbox" (change)="filterHotels(1, one_starscb.checked)">
```

and then update your function to something like this:

```
filterHotels(id:number, checked:boolean){
    this.estrellas[id] = checked;
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(this.estrellas);
    this._hotelService.filter(myJsonString).subscribe(
        response => {this.status = response.status;},
        error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.errorMessage = <any>error;

                if (this.errorMessage != null) {
                    console.log(this.errorMessage);
                    alert("Error en la petición");
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously proposed solutions based on one function to serve two purposes is the best IMHO. But just for your information: if you want to make those two things (assign value and call a function) separately with `(change)` event you can do that with: `(change)="(estrellas[1]=five_starscb.checked) && (filterHotels())"`